# Symfony does not have impersonated role

Tags: security, symfony

I've successfully switched to user with `_switch_user=thomas`.

However, the following always return false when it should return true:

```
        $security = $this->get('security.context');
        $impersonated = $security->isGranted('ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN');
        die(var_dump($impersonated)); // == false
```

Why can't I get the ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN in the security context?

**EDIT**
I log in with:

```
?_switch_user=john@doe.com
```

since:

```
providers:
    main:
        entity:
            property: email
```

my param is the default:

```
switch_user: true
```

I correctly switch, that is not the problem.

The problem is after I've impersonated, the user does not have the ROLE_PREVIOUS_ADMIN

Comment: Have you checked 'access_control:' in the security.yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you haven't implemented the [`EquatableInterface`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/User/EquatableInterface.html) for `User` class:

```
class User implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface, \Serializable {

    // ...

    public function isEqualTo(UserInterface $user) {
        return $this->email === $user->getEmail();
    }

    public function serialize() {
        return serialize(array(
            $this->id,
            $this->email,
        ));
    }

    public function unserialize($serialized) {
        list($this->id, $this->email) = unserialize($serialized);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Can you print-dump `User` object? What is the username value?
- Check inside `config.yml` that impersonation param is indeed called `_switch_user`.

You might be opening you page without actually switching user.

Comment: The user is too big to dump, what are you specifically looking for? It does show the details of the user I impersonated.